# How can I click "Do It!" button with keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, click

This was been question for a long time for me.
How can I click "Do It!" button? Do-It button means, a button will trigger destructive changes. So usually, that's not default button, and I don't know how to click it with keyboard.

I'm asking this because I got a real fantastically suiting situation for need of this.

[image]

Comment: In many slide down alerts like that, you can drag the edges to widen the alert. In your case, that may fix the wrapping, and let you see.

Comment: A stupid question, I recognize the dock-icon with the lily (left to Parallels), but I can't remember the title. What software is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there's just one option hitting <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> should do the trick, as the button should be preselected. If there are more than one option you could tab between them by enabling  **All Controls** under **System Preferences / Keyboard / Full Keyboard Access**.

When tabbing through, a subtle blue glow will highlight the *tabbed* component. Hitting <kbd>Space</kbd> will *use* it, while hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> will *use* the default option.